# How to redirect and show error message without using session in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, session

I have a form:

```
<form action="login" method="post" name="loginForm">
    User Name: <input type="text" name="userName" autofocus>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pwd">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    <a href="register.jsp">Register</a>
</form>
```

Now whenever I hit submit button it will show /login in the address bar. I want to it to show /index.jsp with an error message if user or password do not match.
I used sendRedirect method but how to send the error message? If i have to use session then I must remove the attribute too. What if I do not want to use session and still want to send the error message? How can I achieve that?

Comment: Then you will have to pass the info you need as a GET parameter to the index page.

Comment: If you don't want to use sessions, why do you want to login in the first place? Where do you want to store the information, that the user has logged in successfully? Do you want to reimplement your own kind of session handling?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
response.sendRedirect("/index.jsp?error=something");
```

And retrieve the `param` from your `jsp` like this:

```
Error message :  <%= request.getParameter("error") %>!
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However my browser shows this
index.jsp?loginErrorMsg=<font+color%3Dred>+Either+User+Name+or+password+is+wrong<%2Ffont>
i can read it in the address bar.
Well how to encode this entire message so that no one will understand what happened by looking at the address bar.

Comment: @run_time_error form with Get method show data/attribute values,Post method form doesn't show it.